# how to get info using ast parser

Tags: java, eclipse, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

i want to get info from every class of a .java file so that i can save in a structure (maybe a list) the methods that every method of every class calls. Can anyone help me? thanx!

Comment: Is this homework?  If yes, mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ANTLR](http://antlr.org/) can generate a lexer/parser that will give you an AST.  It has Java grammars ready to go, too.

Comment: thank you, but as i say in the title i have to do that using the ast parser.

Comment: What do you think ANTLR is?  It's a parser generator that can help you create an AST.  That's why I recommended it.